# convert list to json using Jackson

Tags: json, spring, rest

With the below code I have converted list to json but the format is as 
    follows:

```
{"GodownMaster":[{"pname":"FCI CHARLAPALLI","pcode":"16042"},
{"pname":"MLS CIRCLE 1 L.B. NAGAR","pcode":"16016"},{"pname":"MLS CIRCLE 4 
AZAMABAD","pcode":"16003"},{"pname":"MLS CIRCLE 6 
VIDYANAGAR","pcode":"16005"},{"pname":"OTHERS","pcode":"1699"}]}
```

---

but I want to convert it as :

```
[{"pname":"FCI CHARLAPALLI","pcode":"16042"},
{"pname":"MLS CIRCLE 1 L.B. NAGAR","pcode":"16016"},{"pname":"MLS CIRCLE 4 
AZAMABAD","pcode":"16003"},{"pname":"MLS CIRCLE 6 
VIDYANAGAR","pcode":"16005"},{"pname":"OTHERS","pcode":"1699"}]
```

Below is my spring controller :

```
@RequestMapping("/getGodowns")
public @ResponseBody Map 
getGodownsBasedOnDistrict(@RequestParam(value="district_code") String 
dist_code) {

List<CscGodownBean> godown_list = null;
Map<String, List<CscGodownBean>> m = new HashMap();
String exception = null;
try
{
//getting name and codes here
godown_list = scm_service.getGodownListBesedOnDistCode(dist_code);
}catch(Exception ex)
{
ex.printStackTrace();
exception = ex.getMessage();
}

if(godown_list!=null) {
for(int i=0;i<godown_list.size();i++) {
m.put("GodownMaster",godown_list);
}
}
return m;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the return result from `Map` to `List<CscGodownBean>` and put : `retrun godown_list` 
So;

```
@RequestMapping("/getGodowns")
public @ResponseBody List<CscGodownBean>
getGodownsBasedOnDistrict(@RequestParam(value="district_code") String 
dist_code) {

List<CscGodownBean> godown_list = new ArrayList<CscGodownBean>();
String exception = null;
try
{
    //getting name and codes here
    godown_list = scm_service.getGodownListBesedOnDistCode(dist_code);
}catch(Exception ex)
{
   ex.printStackTrace();
   exception = ex.getMessage();
}

return godown_list ;
}
```

**UPDATE**

And you can return result as string and you will get what you need :

```
@RequestMapping("/getGodowns")
public @ResponseBody String
getGodownsBasedOnDistrict(@RequestParam(value="district_code") String 
dist_code) {

List<CscGodownBean> godown_list = new ArrayList<CscGodownBean>();
String exception = null;
try
{
    //getting name and codes here
    godown_list = scm_service.getGodownListBesedOnDistCode(dist_code);
}catch(Exception ex)
{
   ex.printStackTrace();
   exception = ex.getMessage();
}
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    String arrayToJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(godown_list);
    System.out.println("Convert List to JSON :");
    System.out.println(arrayToJson);

return arrayToJson ;
}
```

The returned String is json format.

Comment: not list, I want to convert list to json array format like [{"pname":"FCI CHARLAPALLI","pcode":"16042"},
{"pname":"MLS CIRCLE 1 L.B. NAGAR","pcode":"16016"},{"pname":"MLS CIRCLE 4 
AZAMABAD","pcode":"16003"},{"pname":"MLS CIRCLE 6 
VIDYANAGAR","pcode":"16005"},{"pname":"OTHERS","pcode":"1699"}]

Comment: then I think its is not possible to just return list with Map return type.

Comment: the list will be automatically converted to JSON with Jackson

Comment: @TouzeneMohamedWassim,  I have converted it as {"GodownMaster":[{"pname":"FCI CHARLAPALLI","pcode":"16042"}]} but I want it as [{"pname":"FCI CHARLAPALLI","pcode":"16042"}], [{"pname":"FCI CHARLAPALLI123","pcode":"16042123"}] that means I just want to remove {"GodownMaster": }

Comment: I Have Update my answer. let me know if what you need.

Comment: @TouzeneMohamedWassim, absolutely, I am grateful to you

Comment: Happy to help you :)

Comment: Moving the serialization to the controller is incorrect, since spring mvc has a separate converter layer precisely for that purpose. As it is, this controller method can never be reused to produce, for example, xml. I don't really understand why this got accepted over other, better answers.

Comment: @kewne, is there any way to achieve it.

Comment: @Leffchik's answer is the best one, IMO. The controller returns a `List` which will be serialized to the requested media type by the `MessageConverter`. If JSON is requested, it will be in the format you've specified.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you putting your list into `Map`? Code looks weird. If you want to return a list, just do it:

```
@RequestMapping("/getGodowns")
public @ResponseBody List<CscGodownBean> getGodownsBasedOnDistrict(@RequestParam(value="district_code") String dist_code) {
    List<CscGodownBean> godown_list = null;
    String exception = null;
    try {
        //getting name and codes here
        godown_list = scm_service.getGodownListBesedOnDistCode(dist_code);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        exception = ex.getMessage();
    }
    return godown_list;
}
```

Comment: I want to return json array format as I mentioned above, not a list

Comment: List will be converted to a json array. Try it out

Comment: As @Leffchik mentioned, `List` is one of the Java structures that naturally maps to a JSON array.
`Map` on the other hand, does not map (pun intended) naturally to a JSON array because you'd have to discard all the keys.

Comment: @Leffchik, that's what I am asking, I have converted it as  {"GodownMaster":[{"pname":"FCI CHARLAPALLI","pcode":"16042"}]}                            but I want it as [{"pname":"FCI CHARLAPALLI","pcode":"16042"}], [{"pname":"FCI CHARLAPALLI123","pcode":"16042123"}]    that means I just want to remove {"GodownMaster": }

Comment: please consider adding explaining comment when downvoting others answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have used:

```
@RequestMapping("/alluserreportJSON")
public @ResponseBody String getusersJSON() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    //Set pretty printing of json
    objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    List<AppUser> userlist = null;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    String exception = null;
    String arrayToJson = null;
    try {
        userlist = userService.findAllUsers();
        arrayToJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(userlist);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        exception = ex.getMessage();
    }
    return arrayToJson;
}
```

Hope it helps someone. You can see it working [here](https://github.com/ajkr195/springbootrocks/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spring/boot/rocks/controller/UserController.java).

Answer (score 0):

You add return type as Map, still you want the same  then Just in ajaxComplete() put code;

```
var response = '{"GodownMaster":[{"pname":"FCI CHARLAPALLI","pcode":"16042"}, {"pname":"MLS CIRCLE 1 L.B. NAGAR","pcode":"16016"},{"pname":"MLS CIRCLE 4 AZAMABAD","pcode":"16003"},{"pname":"MLS CIRCLE 6 VIDYANAGAR","pcode":"16005"},{"pname":"OTHERS","pcode":"1699"}]}'


JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(response).GodownMaster);
```

Comment: I want to do it in controller and return the output as [{"pname":"FCI CHARLAPALLI","pcode":"16042"},
{"pname":"MLS CIRCLE 1 L.B. NAGAR","pcode":"16016"},{"pname":"MLS CIRCLE 4 
AZAMABAD","pcode":"16003"},{"pname":"MLS CIRCLE 6 
VIDYANAGAR","pcode":"16005"},{"pname":"OTHERS","pcode":"1699"}]